# How to get children elements dynamically within expandablelistview by clicking parent node in android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am very new to android so could anyone explain very easily about how to make the childList dynamic by clicking the parent?

My problem: I have some static parent in expandablelistview. My intention is, when I will select a parent to see its child, the child will come dynamically form data base and they will be navigable (I want to see more detail or go to a different page.)

I done the static child in three steps.

1. Create XML file with expandablelistview.
2. On main java call adapter
3. Bind adapter with expandablelistview. create custom adapter.

The adapter is following:

```
package com.example.eschool_only_accrdion_straggle;

import android.R.color;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class My_custom_adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;

    String [] parentList={"Summer Fruit", "Winter Fruit", "Hard fruit", "Watery Fruit"};
    // String [][] childList={{"Lychy", "Mango"},{"Banana"},{"Pomy Granade"},{"pani Fruit"}};


    public My_custom_adapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // In Here 1st Parameter is for PARENT and 2nd one is for CHILD

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, 
            boolean arg2, View arg3, ViewGroup arg4) {

        TextView TxtV_child=new TextView(context);
        TxtV_child.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        TxtV_child.setPadding(35, 0, 0, 0);
        TxtV_child.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        TxtV_child.setTextSize(17);
        return TxtV_child;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        return childList[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return parentList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean childPosition, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {
        TextView TxtV_Parent=new TextView(context);
        TxtV_Parent.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
        TxtV_Parent.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 5);
        TxtV_Parent.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        TxtV_Parent.setTextSize(25);
        return TxtV_Parent;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: The title of this question sounds odd if you think about it for a little...

Answer (score 0):

Create an activity extending "ExpandableListActivity", follow for example this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/)

Initialize your data

```
private ArrayList<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>() ;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> children; 
private NewAdapter mNewAdapter = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ....
    groups.add("Summer Fruit");
    groups.add("Winter Fruit");
    groups.add("Hard fruit");
    groups.add("Watery Fruit");

    children = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("Lychy");
    a.add("Mango");
    children.add(a);

    a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("Banana");
    children.add(a);

    a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("Pomy Granade");
    children.add(a);


    a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("pani Fruit");
    children.add(a);

    mNewAdapter = new NewAdapter(groups, children);
    mNewAdapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),this);
    getExpandableListView().setAdapter(mNewAdapter);
    int cpt = mNewAdapter.getGroupCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < cpt; i++ ){
        getExpandableListView().expandGroup(i);
    }
}
```

Then be sure to overwrite the following method into your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // Do here what you need to do when a child is selected
    return true;
}
```

Add finally add your adapter

```
class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    public Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<String> groups;
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> points;

    public NewAdapter(ArrayList<String> groups, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> points){
        this.groups = groups;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
        this.minflater = mInflater;
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) points.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean childPosition, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {
        // ...
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ....
        return v;
    }
}
```

Within the adapter be sure to have the  isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) returning "true".

Comment: dear Guillaume, thanks for your answer. could you plz tell me the function of mNewAdapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),this);  and  and also function of setInflater.  ---- gratefull to you mate---

Comment: You should use the inflater to "draw" your content into the "View getGroupView(..)" and "View getGroupView(...)" methods. Using the inlfater to do this allows you to have different layout, xml files, for the group and the child instead of doing this programmatically. Doing this will give you more control... Have a look into this tutorial ( point 2 and 3 ) : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/